# wxPython for Python 2.4.3 on Windows 7

Tags: python, dll, wxpython

My company server uses Python 2.4.3. I need to use wxPython, but current version of wxPython requires either Python 2.6 or 2.7.

How do I get wxPython to work with Python 2.4.3 on Windows 7?

http://www.wxpython.org/download.php

P.S. I tried installing "wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-py26" and import wx, but got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in -toplevel-
import wx
File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\__init__.py", line 45, in -toplevel-
from wx._core import *
File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_core.py", line 4, in -toplevel-
import _core_
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out.

Since "wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-py26" (wxPython 2.8.12.1) requires Python 2.6, it would not work if I have Python 2.4.

So I found wxPython 2.8.10.1 which supports Python 2.4, installed it and it works!